# imap reading my emails instead of fething just emails body

Tags: php, imap

i am working with IMAP/pop3 protocols with ssl or without ssl.i have problem that when i open IMAP connection and fetch email bodies and email structure then my email statuses converted into unread to read status its very big problem. please let me know how to solve it. i am using following functions of imap.

```
imap_open
imap_search
imap_header
imap_fetchstructure
imap_fetchbody etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

When calling the `imap_fetchbody` function, specify the `FT_PEEK` option.  As described in [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php), that means "Do not set the `\Seen` flag if not already set".